# Python Pandas: get columns by values in row

Tags: python, pandas, loops, row, sparse-matrix

For the purposes of my clustering algorythm I need to iterate over a word/document matrix row by row, and for every row get the submatrix of all columns where this row has a value of 1, (better even, with the exclusion of the row iterated). 
Say I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': '0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1'.split(),
                 'B': '1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0'.split(),
                 'C': '0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 '.split(),
                 'D': '0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0'.split()})

   w1 w2 w3 w4
0  0  1  0  0
1  1  1  0  0
2  0  0  0  1
3  1  1  1  0
```

I need the code to return for the first row

```
   w2
1  1
2  0
3  1
```

For the second

```
   w1 w2
0  1  0
2  0  0
3  1  1
```

and so on. 
How do I do that? Can't wrap my mind around it using `.iloc`

Comment: second should it be w1 w2 ?

Comment: @Wen sorry, corrected

Comment: What is the significance of the brackets? Do you mean you want to get as an output for the second row a dataframe with columns `w1` and `w2` with just one row of `1 1`?

Comment: @eugenhu The dataframe I want better not include the bracketed row, but that I can do on my own

Comment: nope, just think may be that is not what you are looking for ,:-)

Comment: @Wen it was everything I was looking for, just your first line `l=np.where(df.eq(1), df.columns, 'nan')` returned, in debug mode,  a matrix full of `'nan'`, and everything went wrong from there. I tried it on a different Python interpreter, and it was the same

Comment: @Wen wow finally!  thank you so much, it really worked, I only had to change the equality condition from 1(int) to '1' (str).My bad, i forgot how I created the test matrix

Comment: @LeoZisser  do you want me undelete it ? And you can accept it?

Comment: @Wen guess it would be good for your stats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, I print all those steps in case you need them to understand the process

```
l=np.where(df.eq(1), df.columns, 'nan')
df_list=[]

for y,x in enumerate(l) :
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(x[x!='nan'])
    print(df.drop(y)[x[x!='nan']])
    df_list.append(df.drop(y)[x[x!='nan']]) #you can store those df in a list 


['nan' 'w2' 'nan' 'nan']
0
['w2']
   w2
1   1
2   0
3   1
['w1' 'w2' 'nan' 'nan']
1
['w1' 'w2']
   w1  w2
0   0   1
2   0   0
3   1   1
['nan' 'nan' 'nan' 'w4']
2
['w4']
   w4
0   0
1   0
3   0
['w1' 'w2' 'w3' 'nan']
3
['w1' 'w2' 'w3']
   w1  w2  w3
0   0   1   0
1   1   1   0
2   0   0   0
```